# How to add google service to ADT without using sdk

Tags: android, google-maps, adt

I have a problem: I cannot download the package from SDK because I live in Iran and I cannot access Google service.

Is there any other way to install Google Play Services to my development environment? I use ADT to deploy my app.

Comment: Have no idea for that. Contact Google. They will provide some better way for that.

Comment: Have no idea for that. Contact Google. They will provide some better way for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some [mirrors](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mirrors%20for%20android%20adt) to download what you need or just use [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) or [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) service to change Your IP.